# Sorting a text file with two names the same in Java

Tags: java

I am currently working on a Java project,

below are my attempts at coding so far:

```
     public class MyZoo
{
   // zoo identifier
   private String zooId;
   // a number used in generating a unique identifier for the next animal to be added to the zoo
   private int nextAnimalIdNumber;
   // zstorage for the Animal objects
   private TreeMap<String, List<Animal>> animals;

   /**
    * Create an "empty" zoo.
    *
    * @param zooId an identifier for the zoo, at least three characters long.
    */
   public MyZoo(String zooId)
   {
      this.zooId = zooId.trim().substring(0,3).toUpperCase();
      nextAnimalIdNumber = 0;
      animals = new TreeMap<String, List<Animal>>();
   }

   /**
    * Returns a unique identifier, for an <tt>Animal</tt> object, based on the
    * zoo identifier and the field <tt>nextAnimalIdNumber</tt> which is incremented
    * ready for next time the method is called.
    *
    * @return a unique identifier.
    */
   public String allocateId()
   {
      // increment nextAnimalIdNumber and then construct a six digit string from it
      nextAnimalIdNumber++;
      String s = Integer.toString(nextAnimalIdNumber);
      while ( s.length()<6 )
        s = "0" + s;
      return zooId + "_" +  s;
   }

   /**
    * Adds an animal to the zoo.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
   {
    String animalName = animal.getName();
    // Is there already an animal with the same name?
    if (!animals.containsKey(animalName)){
        // If it is not in the map, create a list
        animals.put(animalName, new ArrayList<Animal>());
    }
    // Now add the animal to the list
    animals.get(animalName).add(animal);
}

   /**
    * Reads <tt>Animal</tt> data from a text file and adds them to the zoo.  The
    * format of the data is specified in the MyZoo coursework assignment.
    *
    * @param animal the Animal object to be added.
    */
   public void readDataFromFile()
   {
      int noOfAnimalsRead = 0;

      // set up an owner for the FileDialog
      JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
      jframe.setVisible(true);
      // use a Filedialog to select a file to read from
      FileDialog fDialog = new FileDialog(jframe, "Read from", FileDialog.LOAD);
      fDialog.setFile("import001.txt");
      fDialog.setDirectory(".");
      fDialog.setVisible(true);
      String fname = fDialog.getFile();
      jframe.dispose();

       File inFile = new File(fname);

    String fileName = "import002.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;


        try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = 
                new FileReader(fileName);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }   

            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();         
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileName + "'");                
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileName + "'");                  

        }

      addAnimal( new Animal("golden eagle", "Eddie", this) );               //
      addAnimal( new Animal("tiger", "Tommy", this) );            
      addAnimal( new Animal("lion", "Leo", this) );         
      addAnimal( new Animal("parrot", "Polly", this) );             
      addAnimal( new Animal("cobra", "Collin", this) );       

      noOfAnimalsRead = 5;                                       

      // this next line should be retained
      System.out.println("no of animals read from file was " + noOfAnimalsRead + "\n");
   }

   /**
    * Prints out details of all animal in the zoo.
    *
    */
   public void printAllAnimals()
   {

      System.out.println("\nDetails for all animals in Zoo " + zooId);
      System.out.println(  "==================================");

      Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();
    // The name of the file to open.
        String fileName = "import001.txt";

        // This will reference one line at a time
        String line = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Animal>> animalEntry : animals.entrySet())
{
    List<Animal> animalsOfAName = animalEntry.getValue();
    for (Animal animal: animalsOfAName){
        // output here, change as appropriate, maybe add the type of animal
        System.out.println(animal.getName());
    }
}
        }
    }
```

however there are text names in the text file (Eddie) which are the same, how do I get the second Eddie to replace the first Eddie without losing alphabetical order, in the addAnimal() the put() uses the name field

Comment: Just confirm, you want to keep only the last Eddie if there is more than one in the file? Or you want to keep all of them?

Comment: What do you mean about losing alphabetical order? TreeMap is sorted.

Comment: Hi yes I would like to keep the last eddie if there is more one, but retain the alphabetical order.

Comment: You can only map 1 object to each key. I suggest changing `TreeMap<String, Animal>` to `TreeMap<String, List<Animal>>` so you can store multiple animals with the same name.

Comment: this is what is says in the assignment brief: If you now "test" your project by reading from the file import002.txt then you might notice that although two animals named Eddie are read from the file, only one appears in the listing if you execute printAllAnimals().  This is because we have used a Map object TreeMap and the call to put() in addAnimal() uses the name field and consequently the second Eddie "replaces" the first one.  Solve this problem without losing the alphabetical ordering by name

Answer (score 1):

Keys must be unique in a `Map` so that is why the second Eddie animal replaces the first one.

To hold multiple objects under the same key, you can declare a `Map` that uses a `List` (or another appropriate Collection) as the value in the key-value pair.

```
TreeMap<String, List<Animal>> animals;
```

Now some logic is needed to handle this when adding animals.

```
public void addAnimal(Animal animal)
{
    String animalName = animal.getName();
    // Is there already an animal with the same name?
    if (!animals.containsKey(animalName){
        // If it is not in the map, create a list
        animals.put(animalName, new ArrayList<Animal>();
    }
    // Now add the animal to the list
    animals.get(animalName).add(animal);
}
```

Now for printing, you need to iterate through the animals for each name:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Animal>> animalEntry : animals.entrySet())
{
    List<Animal> animalsOfAName = animalEntry.getValue();
    for (Animal animal: animalsOfAName){
        // output here, change as appropriate, maybe add the type of animal
        System.out.println(animal.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated my code, However now it wont compile and gives me the error: incompatible types on printAllAnimals method (Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();)

Comment: @jacov In your MyZoo constructor, you're passing in animals to the TreeMap constructor? Just change that to empty constructor `new TreeMap<String, List<Animal>>()`.

Comment: @jacov `animals.values()` will return a `Collection<List<Animal>>` now instead of `Collection<Animal>`

Comment: Hi I have made the changes but its still giving me the same error

Comment: @jacov Did you change `Collection<Animal> c = animals.values();` to `Collection<List<Animal>> c = animals.values();` ? If you're not using it, remove the line.

Comment: been working on this code for few hours now (so I missed that lol), thank you for your help greatly appreciated :)